# Ivy target hangs

Tags: java, ant, ivy, freeze

I did

```
svn checkout http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/trunk/ red5-read-only
```

then

```
cd red5-read-only
ant retrieve
```

and got Ivy hanged.

```
<mypath>\red5-read-only>ant retrieve
Buildfile: <mypath>\red5-read-only\build.xml

retrieve:
     [echo] Ivy conf name: java6
[ivy:resolve] :: Ivy 2.2.0 - 20100923230623 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:resolve] :: loading settings :: file = <mypath>\red5-read-only\ivysettings.xml
[ivy:resolve] :: resolving dependencies :: red5#server;working@Lagrangian [not transitive]
[ivy:resolve]   confs: [java6]
```

Why it can be so?

Comment: try: ant -v retrieve (verbose mode). This will provide more info. Perhaps a repository cannot be reached or is responding slowly.

Comment: @oers I think it's still need solutions because more than one person facing this issue. Thanks,